# Discord.js - How do you list every available text channels in a server?

Tags: discord.js

I want to make a bot that can scan every available text channel ID in a server to object, then select the channel based on the name and channel ID. I already have the code to select channel ID from an object, but the objects are loaded from JSON file.

I know there are codes that can search channel ID from a specific channel name, but I have my reasons.

Is it possible to scan available text channel IDs in a server? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many ways to achieve this, assuming you have a variable named `client` that is an instance of discord.js's [`Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/main/class/Client) then you can do the following.

First, you need to get the guild.

```js
// if you have not disabled caching 
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('<GUILD_ID>')
```

```js
// no cache
const guild = await client.guilds.fetch('<GUILD_ID>')
```

```js
// if you are responding to a message / interaction
const guild = message.guild
```

Then you get all the channels in the guild

```js
// if you have not disabled caching 
let channels = guild.channels.cache
```

```js
// no cache
let channels = await guild.channels.fetch()
```

this will give you a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection) of [`GuildChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/main/class/GuildChannel) objects. If you want to have only text channels then you can do:

```js
channels = channels.map((c) => c.type === "GUILD_TEXT")
```

You can convert the Collection into an array doing the following if you find it easier

```js
channels = [...channels.values()]
```